# How to generate chart from Json format

Tags: json, charts, report

I have an api return Json like this:

```
[{
    "userId":"fozzie",
    "numberOfusers":3
},{
    "userId":"gonzo",
    "numberOfusers":4
},{
    "userId":"kermit",
    "numberOfusers":6
},{
    "userId":"teddy",
    "numberOfusers":5
}]
```

I want to use an open source tool to generate a chart from my api. I tried Jasper Report but I really don't know how to use it.
I tried Google Chart but it generate chart from code, I have to write my Json to it. If my api have some change in the future, I have to re-code it again.
Can you give me some solution for this. What tool I should use? 
p/s: I can't use online tool because I don't want my api become public.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts is one option, charting your data using this library should be very easy. I've modified the answer to the data is updated every 5 seconds.

```js
let allUsers = ["fozzie", "gonzo", "kermit", "miss. piggy", "scooter", "animal", "beaker"];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function createNewData() {
   return allUsers.reduce((res, user) => {
       if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
           res.push({ userId: user, numberOfUsers: getRandomInt(1,10)})
       }
       return res;
   }, []);
}

function chartNewData(data) {
    
  let seriesData = data.map(d => {
      return { name: d.userId, data: [d.numberOfUsers]}
  });
 
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
          type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'User counts'
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Count'
          }
      },
      series: seriesData
  });
}

function updateChartData() {
    let seriesData = createNewData();
    chartNewData(seriesData);
}

updateChartData();
setInterval(updateChartData, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: but how about my json value have some change in future? With this way, I have to fix my code. Moreover, this json just a example, my real json have very much data.

Comment: You can redraw your chart any time the data changes. You just create a new seriesData every time this happens! e.g. onNewData(data => { chartData(data);}); And Highcharts easily handles lots of data, you can plot lots of different chart types, column, bar, pie, scatter etc.

Comment: hmm I'm not familiar with Javascript so example if my json change like I updated on post. How I should code to update the chart by your way? Thank you!

Comment: I'll update my answer with that example. Normally the json will change when you get new data. This will be handled by a callback function like handleNewData or something like that!